# Can't edit config file for the game that I'm trying to mod (Asphalt 8) (Windows Store app)

Tags: asphalt-8

I tried to access ownership, seems like I did, set myself to as owner for the file with full perms, still prompts that I don't have perms for it... more info in the picture:[image]

Comment: The Windows Apps thing is super protected, i spent like 30 minutes once trying to get full access and looking online and everything but couldn't

Comment: indeed, there's no point to even try..